# Using an argument as a command in \newcommand

Tags: macros, fontawesome

So, I'm using the fontawesome package to display icons next to small headings. In essence, the following code

```
{\large \faBook\ } \textbf {Method}\\
```

Creates the following:

[image: Icon of a book followed by "Method"]

Now, I need to do this at multiple points in the document, but with different icons. As such, I attempted the following:

```
\newcommand{\iconHeading}[2]{{\large \fa#1\ } \textbf{#2}\\}

\iconHeading{Book}{Method}
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
Use of \fa doesn't match its definition.
```

So, I'd be curious to know if this is possible in any way?

Just for the sake of reference, fontawesome works in the following way:

```
\faNameOfIcon\
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fontawesome` package defines `\faBook` to do `\faicon{book}`. So you simply solve the issue by doing

```
\newcommand{\iconHeading}[2]{%
  {\large\faicon{#1}}\quad\textbf{#2}%
}
```

calling

```
\iconHeading{book}{Method}
```

The translation rules are simple:

```
Book -> book
SearchPlus -> search-plus
ArrowCircleODown -> arrow-circle-o-down
```

You could also do

```
\newcommand{\iconHeading}[2]{%
  {\large\csname fa#1\endcsname}\quad\textbf{#2}%
}
```

and in this case you would call this like `\iconHeading{Book}{Method}`.

Take your pick.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much. I prefer the first method. Just out of interest, what does `\csname` do?

Comment: @DLJ It builds a command name from the characters up to `\endcsname`. In other words it does what you were trying to do with `\fa#1` which doesn't work because at definition time `\fa` is already stored as a single token.